# How can I find a particular file without extension in Linux?

Tags: linux, search, find

I've wondered recently if there is any way to look for archives|pics|media in Linux dirs?
I can do it using the `find` command like this:

```
find ./ -iname "*.tar"
```

or

```
find ./ -regex ".*\(jpg\|tar\|avi\)$"
```

But what if the needed file doesn't have an extension? 
How do I search for it? Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `find` + `file`:

For example, if you are looking for ASCII text, regardless of extension:

```
find -exec file {} \; | grep ASCII
```

Comment: slightly optimize version: `find -type f -exec file {} \; | grep ASCII`